# How to pass id when image pressed which is inside <a>

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have something like this for the view:

```
<a  title="Post 1" id="car1" >
    <article >
        <figure >
            <img src="img/car1.png" alt="image-1"
                 ng-click="getElementBeingPressed($event)">
            <figcaption>Post 1</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate itaque consequatur illo quis, delectus, incidunt labore.</p>
    </article>
</a>
```

and I have this inside the controller:

```
$scope.getElementBeingPressed = function(event)
{
    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var car = document.getElementById(event.target.id);
    console.log('clicked id is: ' + event.target.id);
}
```

But the problem is that when I press on the image I get this in the console:

> clicked id is:
>
> Empty string passed to getElementById().

so there is no ID being passed. Why is that ?

Please if something is not clear or need extra explaining then comment it out and I will edit the question.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Please put console.log(event) in the function. What is the result ?

Comment: The element being pressed is the `<img>` tag, hence why your `ng-click` triggered. The `<img>` tag doesn't have an ID.

Comment: event.target will be the object where the event (click) occurred which is the image tag here. It does not have an id. if you want to get the id of the anchor tag, then you have to move the ng-click to the anchor tag

Comment: @WolfgangBlessen I got this `click { target: img, buttons: 0, clientX: 262, clientY: 158, layerX: 262, layerY: 158 }`

Comment: @Protozoid I see. I moved the ID to the image and it worked. Thanks so much

Comment: @PrabhuThomas I see. I moved the ID to the image and it worked. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is taking the img, but if you want to get the link (anchor), put the event in the link.

Answer (score 1):

The element being pressed is the `<img>` tag, hence why your `ng-click` triggered.

The `<img>` tag doesn't have an ID.
If you want to get the `<a>` tag's ID using that logic, move the `ng-click` on the `<a>` tag, as such:

```
<a  title="Post 1" id="car1" ng-click="getElementBeingPressed($event)">
    <article >
        <figure >
            <img src="img/car1.png" alt="image-1">
            <figcaption>Post 1</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate itaque consequatur illo quis, delectus, incidunt labore.</p>
    </article>
</a>
```

Comment: I did that but for some weird reason it didn't work. What worked was moving the ID to the img instead of the <a>

Answer (score 1):

You should consider to move ng-click to anchor tag, or leave it on img tag, and find third level parent of event.target